# Failed to find Qt component "Widgets" config file at ""

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt6

I'm setting up a new computer as development machine and working with cmake that worked just fine on another computer.

I have installed Qt6 to my home directory, whereas on the old computer, it was installed into the `/opt` directory.

Here is what CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
 set(Qt_DIR "~/Qt/6.1.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/")
 set(Qt_version 6)
 ...
 find_package(Qt${Qt_version} COMPONENTS Core Widgets   REQUIRED)
```

That fails with following error message:

```
CMake Error at GUI/CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /home/menkaur/Qt/6.1.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

  but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Failed to find Qt component "Widgets" config file at ""
```

The file `~/Qt/6.1.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Widgets/Qt6WidgetsConfig.cmake` does exist

Is there some additional configuration that I'm supposed to have had done?

Comment: I am very unsure that `~` correctly works inside CMake. Try to replace it with `/home/menkaur`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trolltech installer does not check for dependencies during installation, instead the dependencies are checked in `find_package(qt_module)`. And if the dependencies are not found, then `find_package(qt_module)` will fail without error messages. Thus, you should make sure that the system has all the [required development libraries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux.html).

Answer (score 7):

Qt needs some package to be installed to work
to install dependencies type the following code and get working

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `set(Qt_DIR "~/Qt/6.1.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/")`, run cmake with `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/Qt/6.1.2/gcc_64`.

Comment: This helped me while trying to compile OpenCV from source with `-D WITH_QT=6`.